# Restoring Android WebView page with ViewModel after device rotation / split view

Tags: javascript, android, webview, rotation, viewmodel

I use WebView to show data, the data gets augmented via JS function.  It works fine until the device gets rotated.  Using ViewModel to keep the page data and restore it after a config change seemed to be the right idea but I ran into problems, the page didn't get restored.  I pared down my code to a minimalist example, included here (sans the XML layout)

---

DataStore class to store the data, overriding ViewModel, simply store some strings in a list

```
package com.automationce.labyrinth.webview;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/* The idea is to use ViewModel to store page data
* so it can be restored on device rotate/split view */
public final class DataStore extends ViewModel {
   public List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();

   public DataStore() {
      super();
   }
}
```

Simple web view class, overriding WebView

```
package com.automationce.labyrinth.webview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public final class SimpleWebView extends WebView {
   // Use to keep and restore data between config changes
   // (not related to browser history by any means)
   private DataStore dataStore;

   public SimpleWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

      // Define style, write JS function(s)
      String content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" +
            "<style>" +
            "span { font-size: " +
            0.875 +
            "em; } " +
            "</style>" +
            "</head><body id=\"body\">" +
            jsFunctions() + "</body></html>";

      loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
   }

   // JS function(s) as written to the page
   private String jsFunctions() {
      return "<script>" +
            "function append (string) { " +
            "var body = document.getElementById('body');" +
            "var block = document.createElement('span');" +
            "var text = document.createTextNode(string);" +
            "var br = document.createElement('br'); " +
            "block.appendChild(text);" +
            "block.appendChild(br); " +
            "body.appendChild(block);" +
            "block.scrollIntoView();" +
            " }" +
            "</script>";
   }

   public void setHistory (final DataStore storedData) {
      dataStore = storedData;
   }

   // Restore page from DataStore data
   public void restore() {
      for(String record : dataStore.records) {
         evaluateJavascript("append ('" + record + "');", null);
      }
   }

   // Append new data to existing page
   public void append(final String string) {
      dataStore.records.add(string);
      evaluateJavascript("append ('" + string + "');", null);
   }
}
```

And finally the MainActivity itself

```
package com.automationce.labyrinth.webview;

import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private SimpleWebView pageView;
   private Button appendButton;
   private int counter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      DataStore storedData = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataStore.class);

      appendButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
      pageView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
      pageView.setHistory(storedData);
      pageView.restore();

      appendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            append();
         }
      });
   }

   private void append() {
      counter++;
      pageView.append("Some kind of new text " + counter);
   }
}
```

The idea was to preserve the data in ViewModel and restore it during creation.  It took me a while to figure why it doesn't work.  DataStore does get preserved during rotation (I can see all the history data in the DataStore object) but although I see the restore code being executed, it never gets rendered in SimpleWebView.

---

The reason is that while JavaScript function does get correctly written to the page, I am calling restore() from MainActivity.OnCreate **before** the page actually renders.  The JS function gets called and quickly ignored because the page, in reality, doesn't exist as far as WebView is concerned (I think).  Surprisingly, this actually worked on the majority of simulators I use - now I think it shouldn't and I have no clue why it did - until I ran it on a physical device (Galaxy S7), where the restore was ignored

---

My solution was to give my SimpleWebView a new WebViewClient and override its OnPageFinished method and in it restore the content of the page **after** the page finishes loading.  SimpleView constructor ('firstView' boolean flag in the code below gets invalidated after the view reloads for the first time after the device rotation):

```
   public SimpleWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
      getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

      setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.v("PAGE", "finished");
            if (firstView) {
               ((SimpleWebView)view).restore();
            }
         }
      });
     .
     .
```

The web page now gets reconstructed from the persistent data after device rotation/split window.  It seems to work well, without any noticeable load delay (I am dealing with relatively small data set now).

I have looked for solutions, I really don't want to save and restore a String content of the whole page in OnSaveInstanceState / onRestoreInstanceState because in this case, it won't do me any good - I'll have the data but I still need to restore it **after** the page gets rendered

Words of wise I seek from the collective:

- Is my analysis correct?
- Are there better ways of handling this?
- Is there something (an unpleasant production code surprise, etc. - I am pretty new to Android) for which I should be watching out?

Thanks, Jiri